# How to insert a new node as firstChild of parent node

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to insert many nodes, and each new node should be added as the new firstChild node of the parrent;

I managed to add nodes, but at the end of the list:

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                            tr.id = 'id' + data.id;
                            var content = '';
                            content += '<td>' + data.id + '</td><td>' + data.status + '</td>';
                            tr.innerHTML = content;

                            var tbody = document.getElementById('table_body_content').appendChild(tr);
```

the structure of my table is:

```
<table id="monitor_robot" style="border:1px solid #eeeeee;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>STATUS</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body_content">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:
There is no prependchild, but this should do the trick!

```
someParentObject.insertBefore(someChildObject,someParentObject.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying the code of Nikolaj Zander the solution is:

```
                    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    tr.id = 'id' + data.id;
                    var content = '';
                    content += '<td>' + data.id + '</td><td>' + data.status + '</td>';
                    tr.innerHTML = content;

                    //var tbody = document.getElementById('table_body_content').appendChild(tr);
                    var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                    if (tbody.firstChild)
                        tbody.insertBefore(tr, tbody.firstChild);
                    else
                        tbody.appendChild(tr);
```